# TensorFlow installation - pip

Tags: bash, virtualenv

I am following this guide to install pip: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

When I run this command: `. ./venv/bin/activate.fish`

I get the following error:

> -bash: ./venv/bin/activate.fish: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `-d'
>   -bash: ./venv/bin/activate.fish: line 4:`function deactivate  -d "Exit virtualenv and return to normal shell environment"'

Please assist.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command should be

```
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
```

if you are using bash in a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

The script `activate.fish` is intended for `fish` shell. You're running `bash` so it's a wrong script for `bash`. With `bash` use `activate`:

```
. ./venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: Hi there were three sets of commands provided: source ./venv/bin/activate  # sh, bash, or zsh

. ./venv/bin/activate.fish  # fish

source ./venv/bin/activate.csh  # csh or tcsh....... which one is for Mac.

Comment: It depends on your shell. You use bash so use `. ./venv/bin/activate`